# Export / Log to error tracking service

Tags: redux, redux-devtools

Is there a way to get an export of the store state / actions **programmatically** in Production that could be **imported back** into dev tools?

For example I can setup middleware to capture the current state and send that to something like (Trackjs,Sentry, Rollbar) but that lacks all the previous state and actions.

I would like to capture in the same format as exporting from the Redux Dev Tools.

Sample export from Dev Tools

```
 {"monitorState":{},"actionsById":{"0":{"type":"PERFORM_ACTION","action":{"type":"@@INIT"},"timestamp":1471017239656},"1":{"type":"PERFORM_ACTION","action":{"type":"INCREMENT"},"timestamp":1471017242004}},"nextActionId":2,"stagedActionIds":[0,1],"skippedActionIds":[],"committedState":5,"currentStateIndex":1,"computedStates":[{"state":5},{"state":6}]}
```

Comment: You could write a [Custom Monitor](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/issues/3) for redux-devtools. But not sure if it is a good idea to use devtools in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently in development but **you can now push action history right in the extension** see https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remotedev-server/pull/20

Another option is to **save the actions to a JSON file as an array** and import them back in.

That's possible as of https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/173

logger.js

```
let actions = []
export function logActions (stateSanitizer) {
  return store => next => action => {
    actions.push(action)
    return next(action)
  }
}
```

These actions can be saved to a file or database and can be imported back into the dev tools.

Sample actions

```
[{
    "type": "INCREMENT"
  }, {
    "type": "DECREMENT"
  }, {
    "type": "DECREMENT"
  }, {
    "type": "DECREMENT"
  }, {
    "type": "DECREMENT"
  }]
```

I created this repo which demos this in action https://github.com/timarney/redux-trackjs-logger it uses middleware to log the actions when an error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a Redux middleware called Raven for Redux which attaches Redux data to Sentry error reports. Currently it adds the following context to each error report:

1. The complete state object.
2. The complete last action object.
3. The `type` of all actions that lead up to the current state. These are added as "breadcrumbs".

The Sentry blog has a writeup describing it in more detail: https://blog.sentry.io/2016/08/24/redux-middleware-error-logging.html

You can find the middleware as an NPM package here: https://github.com/captbaritone/raven-for-redux